# Angular/Jasmine: Can't select buttons with same class

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

**ISSUE:** Can't select and trigger the second button in a template where I have 2 buttons with the same class but different functionality.

**Template:**

```
// Code
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-lr-button" name="add-lr-button" (click)="addLR()">Save</button>

// Code
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-lr-button" name="save-lr-button" (click)="saveLR()" *ngIf="rowDiff.count > 0">Save</button>
```

Basically, in my template I have 2 buttons to submit a form. For each one I'm calling a different method. Exactly the methods that I want to test!

**Test (Approach 1):**

```
it(`should be able to call the addLR method`, async(() => {
      spyOn(component, 'addLR');
      const el = de.query(By.css('#save-lr-button')).nativeElement;
      el.click();
      expect(component.addLR).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));

it(`should be able to call the saveLR method`, async(() => {
      spyOn(component, 'saveLR');
      const el = de.query(By.css('#add-lr-button')).nativeElement;
      el.click();
      expect(component.saveLR).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

**Output:**

> ✘ should be able to call the addLR method FAILED
>
> ```
>     Failed: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null
>
>     TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null
> ```
>
> ✘ should be able to call the saveLR method FAILED
>
> ```
>     Expected spy saveLR to have been called.
> ```

**Test (Approach 2):**

```
beforeEach(() => {
      // code

      // Submit buttons
      submitButtons = de.queryAll(By.css('button.btn-primary'));
    });

it(`should be able to call the addLR method`, async(() => {
      spyOn(component, 'addLR');
      console.info(submitButtons);
      submitButtons[1].nativeElement.click();
      expect(component.addLR).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));

it(`should be able to call the saveLR method`, async(() => {
      spyOn(component, 'saveLR');
      submitButtons[0].nativeElement.click();
      expect(component.saveLR).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
```

I would really like this approach to work, is more generic and avoids the need of adding a `name` attribute or `id` attribute to the buttons in the HTML.

**Output:**

> ✘ should be able to call the addLR method FAILED
>
> ```
>     Expected spy addLR to have been called.
> ```
>
> ✘ should be able to call the saveLR method FAILED
>
> ```
>     Expected spy saveLR to have been called.
> ```

**Test (Approach 3):**

```
it(`should be able to call the addLR method`, async(() => {
      spyOn(component, 'addLR');
      console.info(submitButtons);
      const el = de.query(By.css('button.btn-primary')).nativeElement;
      el.click();
      expect(component.addLR).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));

it(`should be able to call the saveLR method`, async(() => {
      spyOn(component, 'saveLR');
      const el = de.query(By.css('button.btn-primary')).nativeElement;
      el.click();
      expect(component.saveLR).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
```

**Output:**

> ✓ should be able to call the addLR method
>
> ✘ should be able to call the saveLR method FAILED
>
> ```
>     Expected spy saveLR to have been called.
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. It was my mistake to not realize it before.

This is the button that was failing (I remove some attributes to make it more clear):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="saveLR()" *ngIf="rowDiff.count > 0">Save</button>
```

The condition in the `*ngIf` was not being met so the button was unreachable.

So, Solution is:

```
it(`should be able to call the saveLR method`, async(() => {
      spyOn(component, 'saveLR');

      // Making sure it passes the ngIf condition
      component.rowDiff = { count: 1 };
      fixture.detectChanges();

      // Getting instance of the button and triggering it
      submitButtons[0].nativeElement.click();

      expect(component.saveLR).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need CSS selecotrs, no logic behind it whatsoever

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add" id="add-lr-button" name="add-lr-button" (click)="addLR()">Save</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary save" id="save-lr-button" name="save-lr-button" (click)="saveLR()">Save</button>



const el = de.query(By.css('.btn.btn-primary.add')).nativeElement;
```

Otherwise, try calling

```
fixture.detectChanges();
```

To register the click event

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. `fixture.detectChanges();` is not the issue because with the third attempt (I updated my post, was bussy updating when you answered) the first case succeeds. 

What I didn't think of though, is to just add the class without logic!!! I'm trying it right now... I'll let you know!

Comment: I'm retarded. I had an `*ngIf` in the button that fails... That's why it wasn't working. But I +1 you anyway because you pointed out something that didn't come to my mind! Thanks anyway.. ;)

Comment: Ahah no problem, I feel you, I always face this kind of issue. Good luck with your unit testing !

Comment: Thanks! I'll need it! :D